# How to find the optimal threshold for the Weighted f1 score in a binary classification problem

Tags: scikit-learn, precision-recall

I know how to find the optimal threshold for the standard f1 score but do not know how to do so for the weighted f1 score with the **sklearn** library. **Sklearn** provides [a way to compute the weighted f1-score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) by passing `average = 'weighted'`. But it is unclear to me how I can retrieve a list of weighted f1-scores as the probability threshold of my true class prediction varies.

When dealing with the standard f1-score computation, the process is straightforward as I do not need to use the sklearn function to actually compute the f1-score.

For example I do the following:

```
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_score)
f1_scores = 2*recall*precision/(recall+precision)
print('Best threshold: ', thresholds[np.argmax(f1_scores)])
print('Best F1-Score: ', np.max(f1_scores))
```

I suppose the root of my problem is that I do not understand exactly how the "weighted f1-score" is calculated otherwise I could compute it manually as I did with the standard f1-score.

How can I find the **optimal weighted f1 score**?

Comment: Why not look at the probability outputs directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weighted average of any array `a` is just
`weight_avg = sum(a * weights) / sum(weights)` but `numpy` average function accept `weight` as input.

You can compute directly the `weighted_f1_scores` using the the `weights` given by the number of `True` elements of each of the classes in `y_true` which is usually called **support**.

This can be obtained by just **summing by rows** the typical **confusion matrix** (I am referring to the the confusion matrix layout where the true labels are located in the rows and the predictions in the columns).

So assuming that besides the `y_score` you also have a `y_pred` with the default threshold (this is needed by `confusion_matrix` from `sklearn.metrics`, it does not work with scores)

Extending your code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_true, y_score)
f1_scores = 2*recall*precision/(recall+precision)
weights = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).sum(axis=1)
weighted_f1_scores = np.average(f1_scores, weights=weights)
print('Best threshold: ', thresholds[np.argmax(weighted_f1_scores)])
print('Best F1-Score: ', np.max(weighted_f1_scores))
```

Actually `sklearn` is doing this under the hood, just using the `np.average(f1_score, weights=weights)` where `weights = true_sum`. `true_sum` is just the number of the cases for each of the clases wich it computes using the `multilabel_confusion_matrix` but you also can do it with the simpler `confusion_matrix`.  To see it you can see the code in `sklearn.metrics._classification.py`.

Computing the **true_sum** (lines 1464 to 1471):

```
    # Calculate tp_sum, pred_sum, true_sum ###
    samplewise = average == 'samples'
    MCM = multilabel_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred,
                                      sample_weight=sample_weight,
                                      labels=labels, samplewise=samplewise)
    tp_sum = MCM[:, 1, 1]
    pred_sum = tp_sum + MCM[:, 0, 1]
    true_sum = tp_sum + MCM[:, 1, 0]
```

Now applying the **weighted average pre-processing** (lines 1507 to 1526) which is basically assigning unless there are 0 cases:

```
    # Average the results
    if average == 'weighted':
        weights = true_sum
        if weights.sum() == 0:
            zero_division_value = np.float64(1.0)
     ....
```

And finally **computing the weighted average** (lines 1533 to 1540):

```
    if average is not None:
        assert average != 'binary' or len(precision) == 1
        precision = np.average(precision, weights=weights)
        recall = np.average(recall, weights=weights)
        f_score = np.average(f_score, weights=weights)
        true_sum = None  # return no support

   return precision, recall, f_score, true_sum
```